# Add Last Login to Users api call

Tags: desire2learn

Our customer wants to see a report of all their current users' last login dates, but I couldn't find a way to get that information from the current API:

http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html

It's a little frustrating, because it's so easy to get this data in the UI itself:[image: Brightspace Users]

Is there any way we can get that data through the API? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to get this information via an API call; however, you are not the first person to inquire about this, and I suspect it's on D2L's list of improvement items for their developer platform.